# Performing a function inside sub-directories?

Tags: powershell

To start off, please excuse my lack of knowledge.. I am very new to programming. Regardless, I have been tasked with trying to create a Powershell script that will run inside of our FTP server directory that will clean up automated backups that are older.

I need it to go thru each sub-folder inside of the directory - sort by age & delete all but the newest 5 files inside each folder. Ideally, I would like it to be in the parent directory so that I will only have to set up one task to run and manage.

I currently have a script that sort-of does this, but it only leaves the 5 newest files IN THE ENTIRE DIRECTORY. I need it to do it for all sub-folders independently.

My current code that I have tried (and believe it may work with a few variations) is:

```
$path = "C:\temp"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}
$keep = 5
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Thank you all in advance. I have already used this forum many times for various projects and it has come to be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first get all the directories then process them one by one as follows: (see comments in code)

```
$path = "C:\temp"
$keep = 5

#--- Get all the Directories ---
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" -Recurse -Directory

#--- Add Initial Directory to list! Omit if not needed.
$Directories += (Get-Item -Path "$Path")

ForEach( $Dir in $Directories ) {
 
  #--- Get the Files in the current directory ($Dir) ---
  $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($Dir.Fullname)" -File 

  if ($Files.Count -gt $keep) {
      $Files | Sort-Object CreationTime | 
      Select-Object -First ($Files.Count - $keep) | 
      Remove-Item -Force
  }

} #End ForEach
```

Note: code not fully tested!

Comment: Be careful with `CreationTime`.. To find the latest modified files better use `LastWriteTime`.